# Is a generic category of sheaves small?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

This is a rather open-ended question, but the title basically says it all.

Given a topological space $X$, and a target category $\mathfrak{C}$, there is a notion of a sheaf over $X$. This is an abelian category under the assumption that $\mathfrak{C}$ is. Suppose we talk about nice topological spaces, such as manifolds or varieties, and nice target categories, such as abelian groups, modules, vector spaces, or whatever other nicety you prefer.

Is the category of sheaves over some object of your nice topological category a small category in general?

Comment: No, not even essentially small; sheaves can take values with arbitrarily large cardinalities.

Comment: I think my question is what happens generically, not just what is possible.

Comment: The category of sheaves is essentially small if and only if the space is the empty space.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan where can I see a proof of that fact?

Comment: @AlfredYerger if C is sets, for instance, then coproducts of the terminal sheaf form a large family of non-isomorphic objects. Similar arguments work in any reasonable case.